# When you build an iOS app for testing, can you have it end up in a folder?

Tags: ios, xcode

This has been a really difficult question to Google: When you click on build, and Xcode puts the app on your physical iPhone, is there a way to force that app into a folder, rather than just the first open spot on the springboard?

Comment: Either you run your app on device or simulator the products folder contains the binary with .app extension.

Comment: I doubt that if that app binary is useful because for distributing the ipa file Xcode provides the archiving method.

Comment: I’m referring to a folder on the iPhone. Not the .app bundle itself. M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to tell Xcode where to install the app on your iOS device the first time you send the app to the device.

Of course after the initial installation you can put the app where you want it on the iOS device and then it will stay there each time you update the app through Xcode. But if you remove the app from the iOS device and then do a build through Xcode, the app will get put in the first open spot again.

Comment: You can build the app and then "side-load" it onto the device and put it wherever you like. But I don't know if that can be automated.